# Texturing objects with tiled textures

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, gltf

I am attempting to texture an object with a repeating texture which is intended to be 1m x 1m in physical dimensions. So for an object 30m x 20m, the texture will repeat 30 times in the longer dimension and 20 times in the shorter dimension.

I know I can scale the UV map of an object to match the dimension of the object, but this seems tedious to do for every single object, and should I tweak the size of an object I will then have to similarly tweak the UV map scale. I also know I can set the Vector input to the Image Texture in my material to Geometry | Position to get the intended effect on all objects which use the material. However, this strategy does not export to glTF files, and I need to export my environments to glTF files for use in the game engine I am using.

I am fairly new to Blender so it is highly probable I'm missing something very simple, any assistance in finding how to apply tiled textures that can be exported to glTF files would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert for this, but [gltf material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#) is based on PBR that use only UV coordinates for image texture (if I'm right) so I dont think you have other chance than to manipulate UVmap in blender (there was some addon to matching all UVmaps across blend file to global scale) ... or set coordinates as global and when finised bake all textures, but it will generate biggeramount of data then tiled texture of course.

Comment: @vklidu is correct, the glTF exporter (and the glTF format) only accept UV maps as texture coordinates.  There are many ways to automate things in Blender, so you should search for an option, addon, or script that will auto-adjust UV maps to world coordinates.